# Argis .NET WP8.1 draw bitmap layer

Tags: windows-phone-8, bitmap, arcgis

So, my goal is to generate heatmap byte array from C++ code, pass it to C#. Then create BitmapImage (no Bitmap in WP8.1 SDK) from that array and render it as a layer in Arcgis.

Is it possible to render bitmap overlay in arcgis.net?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I didnt found functionality to create bitmap from pixel data array. Instead i used lodepng in C++ to create png and returned that to C# as byte array.
2. In ArcGis i used GraphicsLayer and draw that heatmap png as PictureMarker.